# jquery selector for get value specific form

Tags: jquery

[image]

when I take value from dress, but jquery display value from shoes, what jquery selector for solve my problem?
before i use code :

```
$(document).delegate(".product", "submit", function(){
    alert($(".name").val());
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML? shoes and dresses are what? classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.name` is a class selector and will find multiple instances. Then when you call `.val()` it will get the first instance value only. You need to be more specific, I would suggest making use of `this` (which will be the form) and then finding the `.name` element within that form (which looks like it will be a unique combination). Something like this:

```
$(document).delegate(".product", "submit", function(){
    var $form = $(this);//get the current form being submitted
    var $name = $form.find(".name");//find the name element relative to the form
    alert($name.val());//alert the correct relative name value
    return false;
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/T3762/)

---

NOTE: `delegate` has been superseded by the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as of JQuery 1.7. Which you would use like so:

```
$(".product").on("submit", function(){
   //code
}
```

[Here is an example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/T3762/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).delegate(".product", "submit", function(){
    alert($(this).find('.name').val());
    return false;
});
```